# Why doesn't require add all names?

Tags: ruby

I have a file, `my_helper.rb`, that looks like this:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'enumerator'

module MyHelper
  # ...
end

class MyUpstreamError < StandardError
  # ...
end
```

When I `require 'my_helper'` elsewhere, `MyHelper` becomes visible, but `MyUpstreamError` does not. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a filename conflict. There was another file named `my_helper.rb`, which I had never edited, in a `helpers` directory in my Rails setup. It was shadowing this file, which was in `lib`.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's require is analogous to include in C.

You might want to have a read though:
http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/including_other_files_in_ruby.html
http://ionrails.com/2009/09/19/ruby_require-vs-load-vs-include-vs-extend/